# Computing worldspace MeshLoop normals

Tags: python, mesh, normals, loop

Docs say MeshLoop normals are in local space, which makes sense, but I need them in worldspace for my application. Is this a local space relative to the mesh surface? Or relative to the object transformation? How can I compute the transformation matrix that takes them to world space? I haven't found this in the docs anywhere yet.